# Gostaria de tirar o case sensitive de uma busca em .PHP

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="divBusca">
                  <input class="txtBusca" type="text" name="Tópicos"
                  id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar por item..."/>
                  <br><br><br>
          </div>
          <br>
        <ul id="ulItens">
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Agenda </a></li>

                  <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <button> Pedidos </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> + Pedidos </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Todos Pedidos </a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Todos Pedidos LOJAVIRTUAL </a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Acompanhamento das vendas online </a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Boletos Vencidos </a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <button> eCommerce </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Todos Pedidos </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Total itens </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar</a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar manual </a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Faturamento </a></li> 
                    </ul>
                  </li>
        </ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
        var texto = $(this).val();
        $("#ulItens li").css("display", "block");

        $("#ulItens li").each(function(){
            if($(this).text().indexOf(texto) < 0){
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Que busca é essa? Onde o PHP está na história?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seja bem-vindo ao stackoverflow em português.

Infelizmente o javascript não possui um função específica para desativar o case sensitive, mas você consegue fazer sua busca tratando sua entrada e a string que você quer comparar.

Experimente converter a entrada da busca tudo para minúsculo ou maiúsculo e a string que você quer comparar também (antes de realizar a comparação).

No seu código experimente trocar:

- `var texto = $(this).val();` para `var texto = $(this).val().toLowerCase()`;
- `if($(this).text().indexOf(texto)` para `if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(texto)`

Seu código alterado deverá parecer com este:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
        var texto = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#ulItens li").css("display", "block");

        $("#ulItens li").each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) < 0){
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Observação**

- A função `toLowerCase()` no javascript converte as letras de uma string para *minúcuslas*
- A função `toUpperCase()` converte as letras de uma string para *MAIÚSCULAS*.

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!
Como eu faria para ler independente da acentuação tbm?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca tudo em uppercase. Por exemplo:

```
var texto = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
$("#ulItens li").css("display", "block");

$("#ulItens li").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto) < 0){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é PHP é Javascript.

Você pode converter, tanto a busca como o padrão de busca, para maiúsculas ou minúsculas.

Busca insensível convertendo os textos para minúsculas:

```js
if( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) < 0){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
  }
```

Busca insensível convertendo ambos os textos para maiúsculas :

```
if( $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) < 0){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
  }
```

Comment: Como eu faria para ler independente da acentuação tbm?